# Need a certain Mysql Query Selection

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a MYSQL Query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM quotenumberlogbob 
WHERE LEFT(`quotenumber`, 2) = '$year' 
AND revision = 0 
ORDER BY quotenumber DESC
```

`$year` is a variable filled by the PHP file.

The table structure is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE quotenumberlogbob(
    id INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    quoteNumber VARCHAR(255),
    date VARCHAR(255),
    buildingType VARCHAR(255),
    Amount VARCHAR(255),
    contactName VARCHAR(255),
    repName VARCHAR(255),
    company VARCHAR(255),
    lengthft VARCHAR(255),
    widthft VARCHAR(255),
    heightft VARCHAR(255),
    revision VARCHAR(255),
    status VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    lengthin VARCHAR(255),
    widthin VARCHAR(255),
    heightin VARCHAR(255),
    year VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT `PRIMARY` PRIMARY KEY (id, status)
);
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to show only the highest 'revision' for each 'quotenumber'.

Where an example table might be:

```
| ID    | quotenumber | revision | contactName | Price | Etc |
|-------|-------------|----------|-------------|-------|-----|
| 135   | 1609-4568   | 0        | Joe         | $1350 |     |
| 136   | 1609-4568   | 1        | Joe         | $1900 |     |
| 137   | 1609-4568   | 2        | Joe         | $2650 |     |
| 138   | 1609-4569   | 0        | Mike        | $1500 |     |
| 139   | 1609-4570   | 0        | Steve       | $1600 |     |
| 140   | 1609-4570   | 1        | Steve       | $1900 |     |
| 141   | 1609-4571   | 0        | Zack        | $1590 |     |
| 142   | 1609-4572   | 0        | Bob         | $6050 |     |
```

What I want to see is:

```
| ID    | quotenumber | revision | contactName | Price | Etc |
|-------|-------------|----------|-------------|-------|-----|
| 137   | 1609-4568   | 2        | Joe         | $2650 |     |
| 138   | 1609-4569   | 0        | Mike        | $1500 |     |
| 140   | 1609-4570   | 1        | Steve       | $1900 |     |
| 141   | 1609-4571   | 0        | Zack        | $1590 |     |
| 142   | 1609-4572   | 0        | Bob         | $6050 |     |
```

Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM quotenumberlogbob 
WHERE LEFT(`quotenumber`, 2) = '$year' 
AND revision = max(revision)
ORDER BY quotenumber DESC
```

But obviously this doesn't work.

I know I can use PHP Loops to basically do the following, but I am trying to avoid that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT quotenumber
FOR EACH quotenumber
SELECT max(revision) WHERE quotenumber = $quoteNumberFromAbove
SELECT * FROM table WHERE quotenumber  = $quoteNumber AND revision = $revision
```

I feel that this can all be done at once, but I am not experienced enough to know how.

If there is a simple way to do this, please let me know.

Edit: Mike has provided the answer to my question, but I feel it might help to add that here as well.

The query that was needed is:

```
SELECT *
  FROM quotenumberlogbob 
  WHERE (quotenumber,revision)
       IN(
          SELECT quotenumber, max(revision)
            FROM quotenumberlogbob 
           WHERE LEFT(`quotenumber`, 2) = '$year' 
           GROUP BY quotenumber
         )
 ORDER BY quotenumber DESC
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What about that questions seems incomplete to you? I'm more than happy to add additional information, but what I gave seemed more than sufficient, compared to so many others out there.

Comment: See the answer provided in the link. You're not obliged to act upon it. However, it may benefit you if you do.

Comment: I've added the Create Statement above, and I feel that, to the best of my ability, I have explained what I am trying to do and how I've done that.

Comment: I disagree. For a start, the CREATE statement in no way reflects the data set.

Comment: I'm not sure what more you are looking for. I have examples of everything, but I just didn't type out every column, just the ones that are relevant. I am asking as I want to get better at this stuff, and I don't understand. That said, Mike has provided what I was looking for. So I will edit the question above to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM quotenumberlogbob 
 WHERE (quotenumber,revision)
       IN(
          SELECT quotenumber, max(revision)
            FROM quotenumberlogbob 
           WHERE LEFT(`quotenumber`, 2) = '$year' 
           GROUP BY quotenumber
         )
 ORDER BY quotenumber DESC
```

Comment: It looks like that's what I wanted! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
select quotenumber, max(revision ) 
from quotenumberlogbob 
WHERE LEFT(`quotenumber`, 2) = '$year' 
group by quotenumber
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, as it only still shows the information from the lowest revision, but changes the cell for 'revision' to the highest. I need the entire row to be based on the highest revision. Like WHERE LEFT(`quotenumber`, 2) = '$year' AND revision = max(revision).

Comment: I think you should add `GROUP BY` on `contactName`;

Comment: In this case, the contactName doesn't matter, except to display. It needs to order by quoteNumber, then by revision. see Mike's answer above.